# Replace Source Files When Compiling CentOS Kernel with RPM

Tags: compilation, kernel, centos7, rpm

I am trying to modify one of the CentOS (7.6) kernel source file and recompile all of them for later installation.

I followed the guide on wiki.centos to do customized kernel:
https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

I found that in step 5, the RPM method always unpacked source files from tar files and replaced my modification in BUILD/.

Therefore, I changed my way. I put my modification at another place and added a line in `kernel.spec` file under SPECS/ to copy my file into the BUILD/. Namely, one-line with `cp` command is put before `%build` in the `kernel.spec` (after unpacked). However, the compilation went wrong in the `%build` section:

```
...
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Vd6by5
BUILDING A KERNEL FOR x86_64...
USING ARCH=x86_64
...
###
### Now generating an X.509 key pair to be used for signing modules.
###
### If this takes a long time, you might wish to run rngd in the
### background to keep the supply of entropy topped up.  It
### needs to be run as root, and uses a hardware random
### number generator if one is available.
###
Generating a 3072 bit RSA private key
....++
......................................................................................................................................................................................++
writing new private key to 'signing_key.priv'
-----
###
### Key pair generated.
###
  - Including cert /home/user/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.v2.x86_64/centos-kpatch.x509
  - Including cert /home/user/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7/linux-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.v2.x86_64/centos-ldup.x509
  - Including cert signing_key.x509


RPM build errors:
```

Could somebody suggest me a better way to replace the source file in the compilation procedure? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Instead of directly replacing files, we should apply `patch` within RPM to indicate the differences between modified file and original file.

Firstly, use `diff` command to build patch. Then, modify spec file, `kernel.spec`, applying the patch to the building procedure.

This website shows the example when using this way to compile kernel:
https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/29/centos-7-rebuild-kernel-with-src-rpm/

A more clear reference for patching files:
https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#patching-software